# Symfony2 Accessing User Entity Custom repository from Security Token

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a `User` entity class, which is used for authentication provider:

```php
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Aurora\LikeBundle\Entity\UserRepository")
 */
class User implements AdvancedUserInterface
{
    ...
}
```

In the `UserRepository` I have a custom method `getServices()`.
In my controller, I can access the current user by calling `$this->container->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser()` - but it returns only user object (with setters and getters) with no repository methods.

How can I access those from the security context?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Respository isn't related to any particular Entity object. It's related to whole Entity class. So you have UserRepository for User entity but UserRepository for $user object doesn't have much sense.

If you want get repository for some entity (eg. an User entity), you can do it like this:

```
$repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AuroraLikeBundle:User');
```

and just use it:

```
$repository->getServices(); // or
$repository->getServices($userId);
```